# CRM 2011, how do I create an instance of a custom entity using reflection?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am picking up a project left over from someone else so I apologize if I don't get this out right.

I need to be able to dynamically create instance of MS CRM objects as needed without necessarily knowing what it is going to be ahead of time.

It is working for all of the entities that come with CRM by default, but I am having a heck of time getting a solution for custom entities.

What I have is the following.

```
string myAssembly - assemblyPrefix + ObjectInst.Id;
object msdObject = Activator.CreateIntance(Type.GetType(myassembly));
```

Where ObjectInst.Id = Entity logical name.

WHen I do this and `ObjectInst.Id = account` (for example)  or any entity which comes with CRM.  What I want done works great!!

When I do this for any entity which is a custom entity it comes back null.

I am guessing it has to do with the fact the working types are types which come predefined in CRM,  but there has to be a way to do this with custom entities as well. hopefully??

Answer (score 1):

Use the Entity class for all custom entities

[CRM 2011 Entity type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.entity.entity.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, gives me a direction to go; although it is not clicking with what we are trying to do.   But,  shall plod forward - it sure was more than I had!

Answer (score 1):

The entity class can handle any Entity within CRM.  If you want early bound capabilities, you'll need to generate the classes with the [CrmSrvUtil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844.aspx), as well as enabling proxy types with your IOrganizationService.  In either case, you shouldn't need to use reflection to create your object.

Comment: Thanks,  as I said with the other answer - it is a direction to investigate but not jumping out as to how it fits.  The problem is I have no control or knowledge over the entities, they are completely unknown to me.  Available entities are retrieved and then the name handed off to this method which converts the data between systems.  So i need something completely generic that can do this.  It works great with the known entities,  but customs are not.    Much of the problem is I have zero experience with CRM  so a bit overwhelmed. Again though, gives me a direction at least.

Comment: @SkerryAmp describe your problem more in depth.  How are you getting the data?  Webservice?  Database call?  Flat file?  The Entity itself can perform CRUD operations on any CRM entity.  It doesn't have properties to match the fields, but instead stores all the data in the Attributes property collection.